# Stop an if argument in Processing

Tags: if-statement, processing

hi everyone i'm here asking for your help
i've been practicing codding on processing for a month now but i've come to met a big problem right now:

```java
float w=10;   //haut
float x=14;  //haut
float y=10;   // bas
float z=24;  // bas



void setup() { 
frameRate(120);
size(600,600);
background (0);
stroke(255);
smooth();

}

void draw() {
println(frameCount);


line (w,x,y,z);
w=w+10;
x=x;
y=y+10;
z=z;
if ( (w>580) && ( y>580 ) && (frameCount<601)  ) { x=x+30;  w=10;   
z=z+30;      y=10;}
```

the thing is that i want the line to be a bit bended from the 601 frame

like that:

[image]

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing an } at the end.
Here's a possible syntax :

```java
float w=10;   //haut
float x=14;  //haut
float y=10;   // bas
float z=24;  // bas

void setup() { 
    frameRate(120);
    size(600,600);
    background (0);
    stroke(255);
    smooth();
}

void draw() {
    println(frameCount);

    line (w,x,y,z);
    w=w+10;
    x=x;
    y=y+10;
    z=z;
    if ( (w>580) && ( y>580 )  ) {
        x=x+30;
        w=10;   
        z=z+30;
        if (frameCount<=600){
            y = 10;
        }
        else{
            y = 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yet do you know how to have both bended and straigt line on the same line ?

Comment: @ClézioDelescluse If you have a follow up question, please post it as a new question in its own post. But your first stop should be [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).